# Git repository has a different infrastructure than the repository I push from on my local

Tags: git, github

On my local, my infrastructure is fine (my parent repository contains my files, etc.). When I push this repository, it updates a repository that is inside the main GitHub's repository. I tried to pull, but nothing changed. How can I change this?

What is on my local:

[image]

When I push this repository on GitHub itself, it updates this:

[image]

Comment: Have you added and committed those other folders?

Comment: 1. Do you have a `.gitignore` file at local? This is a hidden file that is not visible by just a `ls` without parameters. 2. Do you `git add`ed and `git commit`ed those files? 3. Do you have a wrong Git repository root? It seems you have a directory INSIDE the `frontend-cartographie` folder. Did you opened that in the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Check what is the actual root folder of your local repository:

```sh
# bash session
cd /path/to/frontend-cartographie
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

I suspect the actual `.git` is not in `frontend-cartographie`, but in its parent folder, which would explain why `frontend-cartographie` itself is pushed.